# Vba Excel dialog box

Tags: excel, dialog, vba

I am writing with a small problem which I cannot figure out myself due to my lack of experience. In my work I am using an macro which opens a csv file from our interal company page. The macro is using custom searches for diffrent variants and downloads the data and then filters it accordingly to needs.

I found many answers on this site regarding the same issue, however they are unclear to me as I am newbie in VBA. Could anyone help me or give me some tips on how to choose "open" option in every loop? Thanks in advance for all your tips or solution.

```
Sub getdata()
Dim oIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim htmlsource As String
Dim link As String

    UserForm2.Show

    Set oIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    oIE.Visible = false
    link = "example.com/SearchResult.action?" & "actionType=Search&searchType=Advanced&fromWindow=MainMenu&type=&resLimit=1000&picklist=active&statApp=on&statDraft_h=false&statApp_h=true&statArch_h=false&desc=&sapDesc=&gcasCode=&fnshdProdCode=&ownGBU=BEAUTY+CARE&originator=&isuDateFrm=01NOV2016&isuDateTo=30NOV2016&brndName=&brndAddndm=&prodName=&prodVarit=&prodXVarit=&consumerDBGCAScod=&addiBrndCode=&casNum=&localDesc=&sharingOrg=&authdPlants=plantAuthToUse=&plantAuthToProd=&countryClred=&shrwsupplier=&matGroup=&chmGroup=&matFunc=&pkSize=&pkSizeCount=&recyclePerc=&methdCode=&archDateFrom=&archDateTo=&archReason=&archComment=&unarchDateFrm=&unarchDateTo=&unarchReason=&x=27&y=9"


    oIE.navigate link

        Do Until Not oIE.Busy And oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
        Loop
        htmlsource = RefreshWebsite(htmlsource, oIE, link, rCounter)
        oIE.Visible = false
        link = "http://example.com/CSSSearchExport.action"
           oIE.navigate link

Do Until Not oIE.Busy And oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
        Loop
      'here the dialog box for open/save/save as shows up and I have to click manually.

       oIE.Quit
```

Comment: I will try bumping it once.